# psycopg2 return missing "id" primary key column instead of generate itself

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

Hello I have the following model:

```
@dataclass
class User(Base, TimestampMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    email: str
    password: int
    name: str
    id: Optional[int] = None

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(15), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

When I try to generate a new user with the following code:

```
def insert_user(session: Session, name: str, email: str, password: str) -> None:
    try:
        user = User(name=name, email=email, password=password)
        session.add(user)
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise InsertUserError
    else:
        session.commit()
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR in handlers: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey) missing "id" primary key column
```

I wasn't put the id because I guessed that psycopg2 will generate it itself, but it didn't.

How can I create that field automatically?

Comment: Side note: have you [read through how to use SQLAlchemy with `@dataclasses`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/dataclasses.html)? It uses different patterns that don't match how you are using these, and if `Base` is a regular SQLA base then you'd not want the generated `__init__` that `@dataclass` provides here. You don't need to put your annotations separately (`email: str = Column(...)` works just fine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because a column is marked as a primary key, doesn't mean it has a default value. SQLAlchemy will automatically produce the correct SQL to auto-generate primary keys [only when using an integer-based primary key column](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=postgres#sequences-serial-identity). For UUID primary keys, *you are responsible for defining a default*.

You can use a Python default:

```
id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

(where you imported the `uuid` module). This default is used only when you create SQLAlchemy model instances, not when you insert into the table using SQL generated elsewhere.

If you have installed the [`uuid-osp` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) (e.g. `create extension uuid-ossp`) and want to use the [`uuid_generate_v4` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html#id-1.11.7.55.5) to produce the default *on the server*, you'd use [`server_default` parameter](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/core/defaults.html#server-invoked-ddl-explicit-default-expressions):

```
id = Column(
    UUID(as_uuid=True),
    primary_key=True,
    server_default=func.uuid_generate_v4(),
)
```

where `func` is [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) (`from sqlalchemy.sql import func` should suffice).